# Print out times tables from 1 to 10 with array

Tags: arduino-uno

I would like to `Serial.print();` the multiplication tables, 1 - 10. This is my work so far. Is there an easier way to do this with array? Thanks

```
// "MultiTable"

//Define global array, is this needed? Makes no difference for my output in serial monitor.
//int number[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

//Define variable
int prod;

void setup() {
  // Open serial connection at 9600Bd
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Print the times table for 1

  for(int i = 0; i <=9; i=i+1) {
   prod = i*1+1; 
   Serial.print(prod);
   Serial.print(",  ");
  }

  Serial.println();
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println();


//Print the times table for 2

  for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i=i+1) {
  prod = i*2+2;
   Serial.print(prod);
   Serial.print(",  ");
  }

  Serial.println();
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println();

//Print the times table for 3

  for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i=i+1) {
  prod = i*3+3;
   Serial.print(prod);
   Serial.print(",  ");
  }

  Serial.println();
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: why do you try it on arduino? learn codding on a computer. it is easier

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  I'm not sure how this relates to the Arduino though.  Perhaps it's a question better suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?  You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I have the Arduino connected to my pc and would like to use it both in theory(programming) and practically.

Comment: So is arduino programed in c or c++? I have a textbook with the kit i got and the code in there is pretty different to what I get when i search for help.

Comment: why would you want to store the values?

Comment: note: in your existing code, change the loop to count from 1 to 10 instead of 0 to 9 .... `for(int i = 1; i <= 10 ; i=i+1) {` ..... that way you do not have to do the add in the next line

Comment: Okay, I thought that the first value were supposed to be at "place 0", but maybe that is not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Define global array, is this needed? Makes no difference for my output in serial monitor.
//int number[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

This is not needed, you can use a for lop from 1 to 10.

The void loop will look like this (not checked, no IDE nearby):

```
void loop() 
{
  for (int multiplier = 1; multiplier <= 3; multiplier++)
  {
      for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
      {
         prod = i * multiplier + multiplier; 
         // or: prod = (i + 1) * multiplier;
         Serial.print(prod);
         Serial.print(",  ");
      }

      Serial.println();
      Serial.println();
      delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Some remarks:

- To go to the main for loop (with multiplier):

  - Identify the similar parts
  - Check the differences within each similar part (only the multiplier value, 1, 2 or 3)
  - Make this a for loop and instead of 1, 2, 3 use the multiplier variable
  - Instead if i = i + 1 you can use i++. It means exactly the same.
  - For clearity I put the Serial.println() together. You also can use Serial.print('\r\n\r\n') or Serial.println('\r\n') to achieve the same

Comment: For the record, the line terminator used by `Serial` is CRLF. Thus, a pair of `Serial.println()` is equivalent to `Serial.print("\r\n\r\n")` or `Serial.println("\r\n")`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thank you for the remark, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: What's with the `prod = i * multiplier + 1;`...? Don't you just want to loop from 1 to 10, not 0 to 9, and not add 1 (which should be `i` anyway...)?

Comment: @Majenko I assume that is a question for the OP? I did not make any functional change. Although I would expect prod = (i + 1) * multiplier, but maybe he wants to start from 0.

Comment: But you have `prod = i * multiplier + 1` whereas the OP had, in effect, `i * multiplier + multiplier` (`i * 1 + 1`, `i * 2 + 2`, etc...)

Comment: @Majenko: yes I copied it wrongly; I updated the answer, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @AndreasH If it helps / if it is the correct answer, please press upvote and press the accept answer button.